# Extracting content from a broken site database

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

I am working on a broken Drupal site which doesn't load.

Is it possible to extract the node data from the database and import them into a fresh Drupal installation?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure the data in the database isn't corrupted? That could be the reason the site doesn't load.

Comment: DB seen fine, the error seems to steam from from the Drupal site?

Comment: If Drupal doesn't find the data that should be in the database, it won't work as it should. Are you sure it's not your case? Does the database contain all the data for all the created nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Migrate API to connect to the legacy DB and import the data into a different Drupal instance. See [Migrate API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview).

Comment: The broken site is Drupal 8, my objective is to migrate the the nodes from the broken Site DB into a fresh instance of Drupal instance o Docker. The migration in Drupal core is only allowing me to do so for older Drupal site 6 or 7.

Comment: You may have to do your own migration strategy for the API, or find a contributed module that handles D8 -> D8 migration. Nevertheless, the Migrate API is the answer.